# Query with FireDac bringing some "asian" characters... why?

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I'm having some troubles with FDQuery (FireDac) that I really can't get what's going wrong. I used to have the same code on Delphi 7 + ZeosMySQL and this issue did not happen.

Now, on Delphi 10 Seattle + FireDac, exactly the same code brings some 'chinese' characters. Here's my example:

My table (using MySQL 4.1):

```
CREATE TABLE `tabdollar` (
    `CODIGO` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DOLLAR` FLOAT(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `EMPRESA_USU` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    INDEX `CODIGO` (`CODIGO`))
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I wrote this simple code on a button to show me the result on a label:

```
  qryAux.Close;
  qryAux.SQL.Clear;
  qryAux.SQL.Text := 'show columns from tabdollar';
  qryAux.Open;

  Label1.Caption := qryAux.FieldByName('Type').AsString;
```

This code on Delphi 7 it show the columns type or name correctly. On Delphi 10 Seattle it shows some different characters (probably chinese or japanese, I really don't know).

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Is it there some property on FireDac Query to bring the correctly characters?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using XE5 with FireDac on MySQL 5.x and have had no problems. Could be a Unicode problem http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC) Support depends on your version of delphi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jaydee, but I still don't get the problem. As I said, I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle version 23.0.20618.2753. The unicode of database (MySQL 4.1) and o.s. (Windows) are the same.

Comment: If you're using only `latin1_swedish_ci` collation in your database, use `CharacterSet=latin1` connection parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is an ANSI / UNICODE issue.

Delphi 7 was ANSI (= could not support "chinese" characters), 10 Berlin is UNICODE.

Try using

qryAux.FieldByName('Type').AsANSIString;

and see whether this shows the text you expect.

If it does I have not solved your problem, but you can try to convert your data to UNICODE ...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much Adam, it works perfectly!